# Ошибка CS0012: тип определен в сборке, на которую нет ссылки

Tags: c#, dll, com, idl

Пытаюсь импортировать IAccessible2 https://accessibility.linuxfoundation.org/a11yspecs/ia2/docs/html/.

Нашел .idl-файл в репозитории хрома https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/third_party/iaccessible2, собрал из него .dll, dotPeek показывает содержимое.

Проблема возникла, когда  я начал использовать в коде интерфейс, который наследуется от IAccessible

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, пытаюсь создать переменную с типом IAccessible2

```
public static void Main()
{
   IAccessible2Lib.IAccessible2 a;
}
```

В процессе сборки выдается ошибка

```
Тип "IAccessible" определен в сборке, на которую нет ссылки. Следует добавить ссылку на сборку "Accessibility, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

При том ссылка на сборку Accessibility присутствует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал ставить ссылку на COM-сборку, Framework - разницы никакой. Причем до запуска VS ничего не подсвечивает.

Буду благодарен любой помощи. Заранее спасибо!

UPD: прикрепил определение IAccessible

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой версии сборка `Accessibility` у вас добавлена в проекте?

Comment: Вы половину ответа писали про интерфейс IAccessible2 как вы его импортировали в сборку, а потом вдруг у вас другой интерфейс и другая сборка. Покажите лучше IAccessible - что за интерфейс и в какой сборке.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу. Как я заметил, вне зависимости от того на какую сборку я ссылаюсь (COM-сборка Accessibility 1.1 или Framework-сборка Accessibility 4.0), файл с интерфейсом выглядит одинаково